# How to Center Footer Content to Accommodate Mobile Viewing

Tags: css, html, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I am having an interesting issue with getting the content within my footer area, to stack in the center of the footer, when my media queries are called. While I can adjust the positioning while mobile view test is in a landscape orientation, when I switch to portrait, everything's off. I'm battling back and forth to make the content be centered, no matter which way the footer portion is viewed on the device (landscape or portrait). Here's my code snippet for the footer in general:

```
<!-- FOOTER BEGINS HERE -->
<div id="footer" class="bottom-menu bottom-menu-inverse" style="background-color: #6e6e6e; margin-top: 45px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-2 navbar-brand" style="padding: 0; margin-top: 45px;">
                <a href="#" style="font-family: 'Edwardian Script ITC'; font-size:25px">Young Exekutive</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4" style="width:443px;">
                <ul class="bottom-links">
                    <li><a href="#" onmousedown="resetScroller('home');">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onmousedown="resetScroller('about');">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="quotes.html">+quotes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gallery.html">gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/YoungMedia/videos.html">videos</a></li>   
                    <li><a href="shop.html">shop</a></li>                     
                    <li><a href="#" onmousedown="resetScroller('links');">links</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onmousedown="resetScroller('contact');">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2" style="width:375px;">
                <ul class="bottom-icons" style="list-style: none">    
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="https://facebook.com/" class="fa fa-facebook-square"></a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>                        
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="https://linkedin.com/" class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="https://instagram.com/" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="https://pinterest.com/" class="fa fa-pinterest-square"></a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's the matching portion for the media query in my CSS:

```
/* For Landscape Orientation */

@media(max-width: 768px) {    
#footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    max-height:100%;        
    text-align: center;
}

ul li a {
     margin: -50px;         
 }

div.col-md-2.navbar-brand {
    font-size: small;
    bottom: 30px;
}    
}

/* For Portrait Orientation */

@media(max-width: 480px) {
#footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    max-height:100%;
}

ul li a {
     margin: 150px;
     font-size: small;  
 }

div.col-md-2.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: small;
    bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 75px;
}
}
```

The footer for desktop browser is fine, but see my image upload of how the mobile turns out, with different devices using the ResponiView plug-in for Chrome:

[image]

What am I missing or not doing here folks? I've played with the CSS classes and attributes, but can't find a solution. I know these links/elements can stack, but I can't get it going.

Answer (score 0):

Pls replace this with this css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {    
#footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    max-height:100%;        
    text-align: center;
}

ul li a {
     margin: -50px;         
 }

div.col-md-2.navbar-brand {
    font-size: small;
    bottom: 30px;
}
        .col-md-4 {
        width:100% !important}

        #footer li {
        list-style:none}
        ul, li {
        margin:0 ; padding:0}
        div.col-md-2.navbar-brand {
    bottom: 20px;
    font-size: small;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    padding: 0;margin-top: 2px !important;
}

ul li a {
    font-size: small;
    margin: 5px 0 !important;
}
        #footer {
        padding-bottom:10px;}
}   


@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
#footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

}